# Why is my Vista trial period only 15 days?

Tags: windows-vista

I've recently been forced to reinstall Windows Vista Home Basic after a startup error prevented me from doing anything else. Unfortunately the sticker under my laptop is so faded that I can't read the product key and when trying to activate my OEM product key (which obviously fails) I'm not given an option to call Microsoft's automated phone system (even when not connected to the internet) to help with the activation so my only recourse is to use -rearm on the command line to extend the trial. For some reason this only resets the trial period to 15 days when I was under the impression that it would be 30.

Is there any explanation of this, and ideally a solution to ensure that the trial period is the full 30 days? I just need to keep this laptop running until Windows 10 comes out.

Comment: Depending on the brand of PC, you can order recovery discs to re-install a pre-activated Vista, what brand and model is it?

Comment: HP Compaq Presario CQ61

Comment: Your best bet is to [order recovery disc set from this company](http://www.computersurgeons.com/Default.aspx), not free but HP no longer has them for your model.